# Conditionally send JSON key in fetch

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I would like to "conditionally" send a key value.

Basically, the way it currently is it still sends the field `KEY_TEST` regardless of whether or not it contains a value.

I would like to to NOT send the field at all if there is no value. So it will send `{"text":"blah","KEY_TEST":""}` or `{"text":"blah","KEY_TEST":1}`

In other words...

IF the there **is** a value in `this.props.photo.info[0]`, fetch should send:

```
{"text":"blah","KEY_TEST":1}
```

IF the there is **not** a value in `this.props.photo.info[0]`, fetch should send:

```
{"text":"blah"}
```

Here's my full code:

```
editorUpdate: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     return fetch(URL {
     method: 'PUT',
     body: JSON.stringify({
     "info": [{
            "text": this.state.value.toString('html'),
            "KEY_TEST": this.props.photo && this.props.photo.info && this.props.photo.info[0] && this.props.photo.info[0].pk || '',
      }]
      })
      })
      .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
      .then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
  },
```

Comment: why don't you check before you adding to body?

Comment: Please give me an example of that. I was unaware it could exist inside of the `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Try the below code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
editorUpdate: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var keyTest = (this.props.photo && this.props.photo.info && this.props.photo.info[0]) ? {"KEY_TEST": this.props.photo.info[0].pk} : {}; 
     return fetch(URL {
     method: 'PUT',
     body: JSON.stringify({ info : [ Object.assign({
            "text": this.state.value.toString('html')
      },keyTest)]})
      })
      .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
      .then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
  },
```

Comment: Looks like it will work- just one small adjustment. I'm updating the OP. My JSON field is actually nested. I'm having trouble adjusting it

Comment: What's the trouble for you?

Comment: The data "text" is nested within the string "info". See original post. Such as this `"info": [{"text": 1,"KEY_TEST": 1,}]`. I tried your example but when I try to nest the json within INFO I get an error after `toString('html')`

Comment: I'm trying to write line 3 more efficienctly with Lodash- can you help? This is not returning the pk `var pk = get(this.props, 'photo.info[0].pk', '');`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `lodash`, But i'll try to help you. Try like this `var pk = _.get(this.props, 'photo.info[0].pk', "");`

Comment: Thanks, had no success with that as the `pk` never gets found